# Does vim have the parameters like " mysql -e "?

Tags: vim, command-line-interface

Does vim have the parameters like " mysql -e " ? So that I can edit a file in VIM CLI. Thanks

Comment: It would help if you'd explain what `mysql -e` does and how it's relevant to Vim.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. vim -e starts in ex mode. `:help starting`

Answer (score 0):

Vim and its inspiration, vi, both stand in part for "visual" (as in, not CLI). However, their predecessors are exactly the opposite (e.g. ed, sed, ex). Out of those three, sed is probably the most commonly still used. You can start vim in ex mode or enter it with Q once inside the editor.